# How to pass locale parameter from job into controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-localization, laravel-translatable

On laravel site making Http Post request inside of job handle I need to pass locale parameter.
And this locale must be used in controller.

I use astrotomic/laravel-translatable and defined in config/translatable.php with default  'en' :

```
'locales' => [
    'en',
    'fr',
...



'locale' => null,
...
```

My BannersCRUDTest job

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

class BannersCRUDTest implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle()
    {
        $currentLocale = 'fr'; // I path French

        App::setLocale($currentLocale);
        session()->put('locale', $currentLocale); // That does not work...

        $response = Http::post(route('banners.filter' ));
```

But checking in related Controller with getLocale method I see English

```
class BannerController extends Controller
{

    public function filter(): array
    {
        \Log::info(' -1 BannerController app()->getLocale()::'); // I see 'en' value
        \Log::info(app()->getLocale();
        ...
```

How have I to pass locale from Job to Controller ? I prefer to use App::setLocale, not as parameter in url of request...

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.19",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
"astrotomic/laravel-translatable": "^11.11",
"mxl/laravel-job": "^1.3",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you only need it in filter, why not pass it as a route param in the post request?
`Http::post(route('banners.filter', ['locale' => $currentLocale]));` and then in the controller: `public function filter(string $locale): array {}`

Comment: I search a decision with use App::setLocale, not as parameter in url of request...

Answer (score 0):

You use a job (BannersCRUDTest) to set locale from 'en' to 'fr'

This job of yours is set to be queued.

- Make sure you have call / dispatch this job properly.
- And also make sure the queue process is properly run.

Comment: Could you please to detalize what do you mean "properly run" ?

Comment: have you run queue:work either using supervisor or cron job
and 
check your database table jobs, is your queue still there?

Comment: I run command :
php artisan job:dispatchNow BannersCRUDTest
so it must be run immediately

Actually I need to write some tests for my API and I used jobs as container to run requests
with Http::post. Maybe jobs are not good place for it? I know there are also actions, console commands but not sure.

I prefer to have locale already set in my controller( with use of App::setLocale in job) , not as parameter in url of request...
about difference...

Comment: @PetroGromovo if you need to run it immediately, either remove extends ShouldQueue, or indeed like what you said, use Action class (best for a single purpose class).

Where did this job getting dispatch? Called within a POST controller ?

Or another solution is by using middleware, checking default locale selected by a user.

Comment: As Action class is best for a single purpose class - how can I run it from console? I choose jobs as they can be run from console, but looks like there are no any command like "php artisan make:action ActionName". What xan be used here that can be run from console ?

Comment: you can use php artisan make:command, and call this action class from that particular command

and as for create Action class, you need to create it manually

Comment: @PetroGromovo here is a link to help you start create an artisan command https://www.cloudways.com/blog/custom-artisan-commands-laravel/#custom